# Smallest palindrome divisible by the input

Tags: code-golf, number, palindrome, integer, division

Given a positive integer `N`, output the smallest positive integer such that this number is a palindrome (i.e. is its own reverse) and is divisible by `N`.

The palindrome (i.e. the output) must not need a leading zero to be a palindrome, e.g. `080` is not the valid answer for `16`.

The input will never be a multiple of 10, because of the previous reason.

Your program may take as much time as necessary, even if in practice it would be way too long to output the answer.

#### Inputs and outputs

- You may take the input through `STDIN`, as a function argument, or anything similar.
- You may print the output to `STDOUT`, return it from a function, or anything similar.
- Inputs and outputs must be in the decimal base.

#### Test cases

```
N        Output
1        1
2        2
16       272
17       272
42       252
111      111
302      87278
1234     28382
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Will the input be divisible by 10?

Comment: @LeakyNun No, because then there is no solution since the palindrome must not need a leading zero. I will make that explicit.

Comment: Will the input be positive?

Comment: @WheatWizard Yes: *Given a positive integer `N`*

Comment: @Fatalize sorry.  I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: Base 10 is mandatory?

Comment: @corsiKa Yes, unless your language does not support base 10 (which I highly doubt)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable) / [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), 6 / 7 bytes

**2sable**

```
[DÂQ#+
```

**Explanation**

```
[         # infinite loop
 D        # duplicate current number
  Â       # bifurcate
   Q#     # if the number is equal to its reverse, break loop
     +    # add input
          # implicitly print
```

[Try it online](http://2sable.tryitonline.net/#code=W0TDglEjKw&input=MzAy)

**05AB1E**

```
[DÂQ#¹+
```

The difference to the 2sable code is that input is only implicit once in 05AB1E, so here we need `¹` to get the first input again.

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W0TDglEjwrkr&input=MzAy)

Saved 1 byte with 2sable as suggested by [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)

Comment: @Fatalize I was just writing it up :)

Comment: If you switch to 2sable, you can save a byte by doing this: `[DÂQ#+`.

Comment: @Adnan: Right! The repeated implicit input saves a byte :)

Answer (score 14):

## Haskell, <s>45</s> <s>37</s> 34 bytes

```
(+)>>=until((reverse>>=(==)).show)
```

Answer (score 13):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
*f_I`*Q
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Af_I%60%2AQ&input=1234&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
*f_I`*QT)Q   implicit endings, Q=input number
 f      )    find the first number T >= 1, which satisfies:
     *QT        product of Q and T
    `           as string
  _I            is invariant under inversion (=palindrom)
*        Q   multiply this number with Q and print
```

Comment: After reading so many codegold questions I'm starting to think that Pyth will be next JS/Java/Ruby/Python...

Comment: @agilob oh dear god pls no.

Answer (score 7):

## **Java, <s>164</s> <s>159</s> <s>126</s> <s>108</s> 94 bytes**

Golfed version:

```
int c(int a){int x=a;while(!(x+"").equals(new StringBuffer(x+"").reverse()+""))x+=a;return x;}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
int c(int a)
{
    int x = a;
    while (!(x + "").equals(new StringBuffer(x + "").reverse() + ""))
        x += a;
    return x;
}
```

Shoutout to Emigna and Kevin Cruijssen for contributing improvements and cutting the bytes almost in half :)

Comment: Isn't `x % a == 0` kind of redundant when you initialize x as a and only increase it by a? Also, can the comparison with the reversal of the string be done in the while conditional?

Comment: You can remove `import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;` and use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.reverse` directly. `for(;;)` is shorter than `while(1>0)`. No need for a full program, just `int c(int a){...}` would do as a valid answer, since the question has the following rule: "_You may take the input as a function argument. You may return the output from a function._" @Emigna is indeed right that the modulo check isn't necessary.

Comment: Oh, and welcome of course! You might like this post: [Tips for golfing in Java](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java).

Comment: @Emigna: you're absolutely right, did that.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: since I only iterate through numbers which are divisible by a (by `x += a`). I don't have to check for divisibility :) and thanks for the golfing tips!

Comment: Also, why did you use `StringUtils.reverse`? Because of the required `org.apache.commons.lang.` it's actually longer than `new StringBuffer(x+"").reverse()+""`..

Comment: @peech Yeah, I noticed the smart `x+=a` after I made that last comment. I removed that part before the 5 minutes had past and I wouldn't have been able to edit my comment.  (I also deleted my own Java answer, since it was pretty bad..)

Comment: You can remove `{}` from the while-loop as there's only 1 statement inside, can't you?

Comment: Oh, also, since you're new: It's nice to add a link with your test-code so others can verify it works. I personally use ideone.com for this, but there are other online compilers available. [Here is your code with a test-ideone.](https://ideone.com/Yu08Wc) Feel free to fork it and make changes if you need/want to.

Comment: Interesting: converting to an empty `for` loop produces a function of the exact same size. Usually `for` is slightly smaller in terms of code byte size.

Comment: Yes I tried that but kept the while loop for easier reading.

Answer (score 7):

**C#, <strike>103</strike> 80 Bytes**

```
int f(int p){int x=p;while(x+""!=string.Concat((x+"").Reverse()))x+=p;return x;}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
int f(int p)
{
   int x = p;
   while (x + "" != string.Concat((x + "").Reverse()))
      x += p;
   return x;
}
```

Comment: You might save some bytes by removing i, and incrementing via x+=p.

Comment: replacing `x.ToString()` with 'x+""` will save a bunch of chars.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
:L#>*.r=
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OkwjPioucj0&input=MTIzNA&args=Wg) (around 5 seconds for `1234`)

[Verify all testcases.](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OjFhCjpMIz4qLnI9&input=WzE6MjoxNjoxNzo0MjoxMTE6MzAyOjEyMzRd&args=Wg&debug=on) (around 20 seconds)

```
:L#>*.r=
?:L#>*.r=.   Implicitly filling Input and Output:
             Input is prepended to every predicate,
             Output is appended to every predicate.

?:L  *.      Input*L is Output,
  L#>        L is positive,
      .r .   Output reversed is Output,
        =.   Assign a value to Output.
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,c=0:`c`[::-1]==`c`and c or f(x,c+x)
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/x8gWMH)

Recursive solution with `c` as counter.

The case for `0` is interesting, because although `c=0` satisfies the palindrome condition, it would not be returned, because `ccc and 0 or xxx` always returns `xxx`.

Comment: It's a bit shorter to do ``c*(`c`[::-1]==`c`)or``.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>55</s> 51 bytes

**4 bytes thanks to Neil.**

```js
f=(x,c=x)=>c==[...c+""].reverse().join``?c:f(x,x+c)
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.textContent=this.value%10&&f(+this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Comment: From playing around while creating your code snippet for you, the first `+` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Would `(x,c=x)` allow you to avoid the `&&c`?

Comment: I think you can do `c^[...c+""].reverse().join``?f(x,x+c):c` to save one more byte.

Comment: `c-` would work for slightly higher numbers than `c^`, if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 39 bytes

```
while(strrev($i+=$argv[1])!=$i);echo$i;
```

- Takes number N as argument $argv[1];
- `;` after while to do nothing
- `strrev` return string backward

Same length with for-loop

```
for(;strrev($i+=$argv[1])!=$i;);echo$i;
```

Answer (score 4):

### Pyke, <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
.f*`D_q)*
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.f%2a%60D_q%29%2a&input=16)

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>117</s> <s>113</s> <s>109</s> 101 bytes

```
D=charToRaw;P=paste;S=strtoi;a=P(i<-scan()+1);while(!all(D(a)==rev(D(a))&&S(a)%%i==0)){a=P(S(a)+1)};a
```

**Ungolfed**

```
i<-scan()        #Takes the input

D=charToRaw      #Some aliases
P=paste
S=strtoi
a=P(i+1)         #Initializes the output

while(!(all(D(a)==rev(D(a)))&&(S(a)%%i==0))) #While the output isn't a palindrom and isn't
                                             #divisible by the output...
    a=P(S(a)+1)

a
```

`all(charToRaw(a)==rev(charToRaw(a)))` checks if at each position of `a` the value of `a` and its reverse are the same (i.e., if `a` is palindromic).
It might be possible to golf out some bytes by messing around with the `types`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

Asked to answer by Leaky Nun. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pWWMmDilZwqJDtSPWDilZNO4pWcKg&input=MTIzNA)

```
╖2`╜*$;R=`╓N╜*
```

**Ungolfing**

```
          Implicit input n.
╖         Save n in register 0.
2`...`╓   Push first 2 values where f(x) is truthy, starting with f(0).
  ╜*$       Push register 0, multiply by x, and str().
  ;R        Duplicate str(n*x) and reverse.
  =         Check if str(n*x) == reverse(str(n*x)).
          The map will always result in [0, the x we want].
N         Grab the last (second) value of the resulting list.
╜*        Push n and multiply x by n again.
          Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>217</s> 189 bytes

Standalone version :

```
int a(char*b){int c=strlen(b);for(int i=0;i<c/2;i++)if(b[i]!=b[c-i-1])return 0;}int main(int e,char **f){int b,c;char d[9];b=atoi(f[1]);c=b;while(1){sprintf(d,"%d",c);if(a(d)&&(c/b)*b==c)return printf("%d",c);c++;}}
```

Call to a function version :

```
int s(char*a){int b=strlen(a);for(int i=0;i<b/2;i++)if(a[i]!=a[b-i-1])return 0;}int f(int a){int b;char c[9];b=a;while(1){sprintf(c,"%d",b);if(s(c)&&(b/a)*a==b)return printf("%d",b);b++;}}
```

Ungolfed :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int check_palindrome(char *str) {
  int length = strlen(str);

  for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
    if (str[i] != str[length - i - 1])
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int number;
  int pal;
  char string[15];

  number = atoi(argv[1]);
  pal = number;
  while (1) {
    sprintf(string, "%d", pal);
    if (check_palindrome(string) && (pal / number) * number == pal)
      {
        printf("%d\n", pal);
        return 1;
      }
    pal++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Call to a function ungolfed :

```
int s(char *a) {
  int b = strlen(a);

  for (int i = 0; i < b / 2; i++) {
    if (a[i] != a[b - i - 1])
      return 0;
  }
  return 1; //We can remove it, it leads to a undefined behaviour but it works
}

int f(int a) {
  int b;
  char c[9];

  b = a;
  while (1) {
    sprintf(c, "%d", b);
    if (s(c) && (b / a) * a == b)
      {
        printf("%d\n", b); //no need for the \n
        return 1; //just return whatever printf returns, who cares anyway ?
      }
    b++;
  }
  return 0; //no need for that
}
```

I included the standalone version for historicity.

This is my first codegolf, any comment is welcome !

Comment: I recommend making a separate function for the challenge, and not counting `main()` regardless of your preferences. You wouldn't play baseball by running twelve loops around first before tagging "because I prefer it," you will never reach safely. This is a competition, and the primary rule is to use any means necessary and legal to reduce byte count.

Comment: @Snowman fair enouth, I edited my answer to include a 'call to a function' version. This allows me to take an int as parameter and gold away a few more bytes.

Comment: do your function compile without "include <string.h>"? if the answer is not than i can use #define F for  or #define R return without make it in count...

Comment: @RosLuP yeah, I get a few warnings but gcc is able to compile it.

Comment: Hi!, I would like drop some Hints!   
1) C has implicit int so you can change the code like this `int f(int a)` -> `f(a)`  
2) if you have to declare some `int`s you can use the function parameters: `int f(int a){int b;` -> `f(a,b){`   
3) `sprintf` will never return 0 so you ca use in the `while`: `while(1){sprintf(c,"%d",b);` -> `while(sprintf(c,"%d",b)){`   
4) use the K&R C for define a Function so tou can combo with my 2nd hint: `int s(char*a){int b=strlen(a);for(int i=0` -> `s(a,b,i)char*a;{b=strlen(a);for(i=0;`

Comment: @GiacomoGarabello Thanks for the tips, I didn't know about the default type, that's a pretty neat trick !

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>64 63</s> 56 bytes

```
x!n|mod x n==0,s<-show x,reverse s==s=x|y<-x+1=y!n
(1!)
```

Call with `(1!)16` or simply `1!16`. [Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/qG7FUd)

Answer (score 3):

**VBSCRIPT, 47 bytes**

```
do:i=i+1:a=n*i:loop until a=eval(strreverse(a))
```

**ungolfed**

```
do                     #starts the loop
i=i+1                  #increments i, we do it first to start at 1 instead of 0
a=                     #a is the output
n*i                    #multiply our input n by i
loop until 
a=eval(strreverse(a))  #end the loop when our output is equal to its reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 25 bytes

Includes +2 for `-ap`

Run with the input on STDIN:

```
palidiv.pl <<< 16
```

`palidiv.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -ap
$_+="@F"while$_-reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

## [S.I.L.O.S](http://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 109 bytes

```
readIO 
n = 0
lbla
n + i
a = n
r = 0
lblb
m = a
m % 10
r * 10
r + m
a / 10
if a b
r - n
r |
if r a
printInt n
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=cmVhZElPIApuID0gMApsYmxhCm4gKyBpCmEgPSBuCnIgPSAwCmxibGIKbSA9IGEKbSAlIDEwCnIgKiAxMApyICsgbQphIC8gMTAKaWYgYSBiCnIgLSBuCnIgfAppZiByIGEKcHJpbnRJbnQgbg&input=&args=MzAy)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
V±U s w ¥V?V:ß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@x92aGOoQrFCucKhpWH2YVaH5///b2hkbAIA)

Thank you ETHproductions for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
0`G+tVtP<a
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MGBHK3RWdFA8YQ&input=MTIzNA)

```
0      % Push 0
`      % Do...while
  G+   %   Add the input. This generates the next multiple of the input
  tV   %   Duplicate, convert to string
  tP   %   Duplicate, reverse
  <a   %   Is any digit lower than the one in the reverse string? This is the
       %   loop condition: if true, the loop proceeds with the next iteration
       % End do...while
       % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 76 bytes

```
function s=p(n)
f=1;s='01';while(any(s~=fliplr(s))) s=num2str(n*f);f=f+1;end
```

Call format is `p(302)` result is a string.

Nothing clever here. It does a linear search, using the `num2str()` and `fliplr()` functions.

This ugly arrangement is a touch shorter than using a `while(1) ... if ... break end` pattern.

Ungolfed

```
function s = findFirstPalindromeFactor(n)
  f = 1;                        % factor
  s = '01';                     % non-palindromic string for first try
  while( all(s ~= fliplr(s)) )  % test s not palindrome
    s = num2str( n * f );       % factor of input as string
    f = f + 1;                  % next factor
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 72 bytes

```
for($i=$n=$args[0];;$i+=$n){if($i-eq-join"$i"["$i".Length..0]){$i;exit}}
```

Long because of how reversing is handled in PowerShell -- not very well. ;-)

Takes input `$args[0]`, stores into `$i` (our loop variable) and `$n` (our input). Loops infinitely, incrementing `$i` by `$n` each time (to guarantee divisibility).

Each iteration, we check whether `$i` is a palindrome. There's some trickery happening here, so let me explain. We first take `$i` and stringify it with `"$i"`. That's then array-indexed in reverse order `["$i".length..0]` before being `-join`ed back into a string. That's fed into the right-hand side of the `-eq`uality operator, which implicitly casts the string back into an `[int]`, since that's the left-hand operand. Note: this casting does strip any leading zeros from the palindrome, but since we're guaranteed the input isn't divisible by `10`, that's OK.

Then, `if` it is a palindrome, we simply place `$i` onto the pipeline and `exit`. Output is implicit at the end of execution.

#### Test Cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 1,2,16,17,42,111,302,1234|%{"$_ -> "+(.\smallest-palindrome-divisible-by-input.ps1 $_)}
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
16 -> 272
17 -> 272
42 -> 252
111 -> 111
302 -> 87278
1234 -> 28382
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
(c=#;Not[PalindromeQ@c&&c~Mod~#==0]~While~c++;c)&
```

Starts the search at `c = N`, and increments `c` if not a palindrome and not divisible by `N`. When conditions are met, outputs `c`.

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 12 bytes

```
¹µ+³ßµDU⁼Dµ?
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrnCtSvCs8OfwrVEVeKBvETCtT8&input=&args=MTY)

Explanation:

This link takes 1 argument. The `µ`s split it into 4 parts. Starting from the last and moving left:

```
           ? The three parts in front of this are the if, else, and
             condition of a ternary expression.
      DU⁼D  This condition takes a number n as an argument. It converts
            n to an array of decimal digits, reverses that array, and
            then compares the reversed array to the decimalization of
            n (ie is n palindromic in decimal?)
  +³ß  This is the else. It adds the original input argument to n
       and then repeats the link with the new value of n.
¹  This is the if. It returns the value passed to it.
```

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//wrkrwrPDnyREVeKBvETGsj////8xNg)

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, <strike>66</strike> 65 bytes

`i` is input and `x` is (eventually) output

```python
def f(i,x):
    y=x if x%i==0&&`x`==`x`[::-1]else f(i,x+1)
    return y
```

After scrolling through other answers I found a shorter Python 2 answer but I put the effort into my solution so might as well throw it here. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You can remove the space in `[::-1] else`.

Comment: can't you remove the assignment of y, and just put the expression on the end of the return? `return x if x%i==0&&`x`==`x`[::-1]else f(i,x+1)`, which then means you can make it a lambda, and golf more bytes?

Answer (score 2):

## [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org), 75 bytes

```
def f(p,a\\0),do: if'#{a+p}'|>Enum.reverse=='#{a+p}',do: a+p,else: f(p,a+p)
```

Answer (score 2):

## REXX, 46 bytes

```
arg a
do n=a by a until reverse(n)=n
end
say n
```

Answer (score 2):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 29 bytes

```
:{c=a*q~!c$=_f!c$||_Xc\q=q+1
```

Explanation:

```
:      Get cmd line param as number 'a'
{      DO
c=a*q  multiply 'a' by 'q' (which is 1 at the start of a QBIC program) and assign to 'c'
~      IF
!c$    'c' cast to string
=      equals
_f!c$| 'c' cast to string, the reversed
|      THEN
_Xc    Quit, printing 'c'
\q=q+1 ELSE increment q and rerun
       DO Loop is auto-closed by QBIC, as is the IF
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
x=lambda n,m=0:m*(`m`==`m`[::-1])or x(n,m+n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoQwFEP3niJLqx2wVUYo/JOIoOIMCtOvaBf29J2vi4SQ8LLHsGxsU7roN/ppHsHaU@V8kQ9@IBLrnHuZXm0HrlzGklUKnzOcIHRGw2qYt6jVaO5spKurO9m66bOvcBEr42Ec9mPlIE9RpT8)

I know that the question was posted over six months ago, but this was shorter than any other Python submission.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 35 bytes

```perl6
->\N{first {$_%%N&&$_==.flip},N..*}
```

```perl6
->\N{first {$_==.flip},(N,N*2...*)}
```

```perl6
->\N{(N,N*2...*).first:{$_==.flip}}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
-> \N {
  # from a list of all multiples of the input
  # ( deduced sequence )
  ( N, N * 2 ... * )

  # find the first
  .first:

  # that is a palindrome
  { $_ == .flip }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 39 bytes

```
my &f={first {.flip==$_},($_,2*$_...*)}
```

(33 not including the `my &f=`)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>34</s> 28 bytes

```
#//.x_/;!PalindromeQ@x:>x+#&
```

Unnamed function taking a positive integer input and returning a positive integer. To be read as: "Starting with the function argument `#`, repeatedly replace any `x` we see that is not a palindrome with `x+#`." Yes, Virginia, there is a `PalindromeQ`! It only works in base 10 though.

Original submission:

```
(i=1;While@!PalindromeQ[++i#];i#)&
```

Comment: I count 34, but here's 33: `(i=0;While@!PalindromeQ[i+=#];i)&` or `(For[i=0,!PalindromeQ[i+=#],];i)&` or `(For[i=#,!PalindromeQ@i,i+=#];i)&`.

Comment: Revisiting this answer, I see that I've learned some tricks since August! Down to 28 :)

Comment: Good thing that [duplicate answers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106356/8478) have been allowed since August. ;)

Comment: #$%^&*%#$*&^%!@... ;)

Answer (score 1):

**C, not 83, 80 bytes**

```
f(n,b,k,z){for(b=1;;){for(z=0,k=b*n;z+=k%10,k/=10;z*=10);if(b++*n==z)return z;}}
```

For say the true i had seen in one other puzzle one programmer use the same algo number=swapped(number) => number is palindrome. How is possible to edit barred
text?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{unsigned  a[]={0,1,2,3,16,17,42,111,302,1234}, i;
 for(i=0;i<10;++i)
   printf("f(a[%u])=f(%u)=%u\n", i, a[i], f(a[i], 0, 0, 0)); 
 return 0;
}

/*
 f(a[0])=f(0)=0
 f(a[1])=f(1)=1
 f(a[2])=f(2)=2
 f(a[3])=f(3)=3
 f(a[4])=f(16)=272
 f(a[5])=f(17)=272
 f(a[6])=f(42)=252
 f(a[7])=f(111)=111
 f(a[8])=f(302)=87278
 f(a[9])=f(1234)=28382
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

### dc, <s>85</s> <s>78</s> 76 bytes

```dc
[pq]sq?ddsI[dddZ0sR[1-dsD10r^rdsN10%*lR+sRlN10/lDd0<@]ds@xlR++=q+lIrlLx]dsLx
```

**Run:**

```sh
dc -f program.dc <<< "16"
```

**Output:**

```sh
272
```

**Previously submitted code and explanation:**

```dc
    # loads register 'q' with an exit function
[pq]sq
    # register '@' contains an iterative function to reverse a number (312 to 213),
#by calculating one coefficient at a time of the new base 10 polynomial
[1-dsD10r^rdsN10%*lR+sRlN10/lDd0<@]s@
    # register 'L' implements the logic. It iteratively compares the current value
#with the generated reversed one, exiting if equal, otherwise increments the value
#by N and repeats.
[dddZ0sRl@xlR++=q+lIrlLx]sL
    # the "main". It reads the input, then calls the solver function from 'L'.
?ddsIlLx
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 174 bytes

```
(let((p?(λ(m)(equal? m(string->number(list->string(reverse(string->list(number->string m)))))))))
(let loop((N n))(cond[(and(p? N)(= 0(modulo N n)))N][else(loop(add1 N))])))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f1 n)
  (let ((p? (λ (m)(equal? m
                          (string->number
                           (list->string
                            (reverse
                             (string->list
                              (number->string m)))))))))
    (let loop ((N n))
      (cond
        [(and (p? N) (= 0 (modulo N n))) N]
        [else (loop (add1 N))]
        ))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 1)
(f 2)
(f 16)
(f 17)
(f 42)
(f 111)
(f 302)
(f 1234)
```

Output:

```
1
2
272
272
252
111
87278
28382
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 50 bytes

```
->n{a=n;while(s=a.to_s;s!=s.reverse)do a+=n;end;a}
```

It's horrible, I know.

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 31 Bytes

```
►x=01¿1+]x*]''.S.\''.≡!}x*
```

### Explained

```
►x=01¿1+]x*]''.S.\''.≡!}x*  # ► Defines spaceless segment.
 x=                         # Define the input as x
   01                       # Push 0, 1 to the stack. 1 is used as a truthy for the while, 0 is our incrementing product.
     ¿                 }    # While the value on top of the stack (popped) is truthy. 
      1+                    # Increment the product by one.
        ]x*                 # Duplicate the producter, multiply by the input.
           ]''.S.\''.≡!     # Check to see if the result is a palindrome.
           ]''.             # Push a duplicate of the multiplied number, convert to a string.
               S.           # Convert it to a stack and re-concatinate it. This reverses the string.
                 \''.≡!     # Flip the top two values, exposing the original product. Conver it to a string and test inverse equality.
                        x*  # Once the loop ends, the last number times the input will be a palindrome. Thus, do that.
```

The equality sugar was only added after the discovery of this challenge, as was the bugfix that allowed strings to be used in spaceless segments.

[Try it Online!](https://tehflamintaco.github.io/Reverse-Programmer-Notation/RProgN.html?rpn=%E2%96%BAx%3D01%C2%BF1%2B%5Dx*%5D%27%27.S.%5C%27%27.%E2%89%A1!%7Dx*&input=16)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 71 bytes

```
#(first(for[i(rest(range))i[(str(* % i))]:when(=(seq i)(reverse i))]i))
```

Just one long `for` with a two-step generation of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
#//.x_/;!PalindromeQ@x:>x+#&
```

#### Explanation

```
#//....
```

Repeatedly apply the following substitution to the input.

```
x_/;!PalindromeQ@x
```

Match a value which is not a palindrome.

```
...:>x+#
```

And replace that value with itself plus the input. This repeated substitution therefore searches through consecutive multiples of the input until it finds a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
_s ê¬©ZvU}a1
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=X3Mg6qypWnZVfWEx&input=MTIzNA==)

---

### Alternative

```
_¥sw «ZuU}aÄ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=X6VzdyCrWnVVfWHE&input=NQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
{:Ḃ≠|+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJ7OuG4guKJoHwrIiwiIiwiMTYiXQ==)

Same as my Thunno 2 answer.

##### Explanation

```python
{:Ḃ≠|+  # Implicit input
{       # While loop
 :      # (condition)  duplicate current number
   ≠    #              not equal to
  Ḃ     #              its reverse
    |+  # (body)  add the input
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
(ḲQ;+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSglRTElQjglQjJRJTNCJTJCJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MSUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMC0lM0UlMjAxJTBBMiUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMC0lM0UlMjAyJTBBMTYlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwMjcyJTBBMTclMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwMjcyJTBBNDIlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwMjUyJTBBMTExJTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMDExMSUwQTMwMiUyMCUyMC0lM0UlMjA4NzI3OCUwQTEyMzQlMjAtJTNFJTIwMjgzODImZmxhZ3M9Qw==)

##### Explanation

```python
(ḲQ;+  # Implicit input
(      # While loop
  Q    # (condition)  not equal to
 Ḳ     #              its reverse
   ;+  # (body)  add the input
       # Implicit output
```