# Find the smallest number that doesn't divide N

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

This challenge is simple enough that it's basically all in the title: you're given a positive integer **N** and you should return the smallest positive integer which is not a divisor of **N**.

An example: the divisors of **N = 24** are `1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24`. The smallest positive integer which is not in that list is **5**, so that's the result your solution should find.

This is OEIS sequence [A007978](https://oeis.org/A007978).

### Rules

You may write a [program or a function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419) and use any of the our [standard methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447) of receiving input and providing output.

You may use any [programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2028), but note that [these loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer – measured in *bytes* – wins.

### Test Cases

The first 100 terms are:

```
2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 
3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 
2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 
3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3
```

In particular, make sure that your answer works for inputs **1** and **2** in which case the result is larger than the input.

And for some larger test cases:

```
N          f(N)
1234567    2
12252240   19
232792560  23
```

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 105412; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I turned the sample output string into a vector of numbers, and realized that if you format it 24 columns across, it's extremely repetitive, except for the odd deviation.

Comment: That makes sense, 24 is 0 mod 2, 3, and 4, so the only differences would be in columns where the numbers are >4. It's even more repetitive at width 120.

Answer (score 21):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes (UTF-8 encoding)

```
1//.x_/;x∣#:>x+1&
```

Unnamed function taking a nonzero integer argument and returning a positive integer. The vertical bar about halfway through is actually the three-byte character U+2223, which denotes the divisibility relation in Mathematica. Explanation:

```
1                   Starting with 1,
 //.                apply the following rule until it stops mattering:
    x_                if you see a number x
      /;x∣#           such that x divides the function argument,
           :>x+1      replace it with x+1.
                &   Cool, that's a function.
```

Edited to add: ngenisis points out that `//.` will, by default, iterate a maximum of 65536 times. So this implementation works for all input numbers less than the least common multiple of the integers from 1 to 65538 (in particular, on all numbers with at most 28436 digits), but technically not for all numbers. One can replace `x//.y` with `ReplaceRepeated[x,y,MaxIterations->∞]` to fix this flaw, but obviously at the cost of 34 additional bytes.

Comment: Very interesting way to loop without using `For`, `While`, etc

Comment: I learned it from this site! I'm definitely enjoying learning more about Mathematica by being here (can I justify that on my timesheet...?).

Comment: That does not look like mathematica O_o

Comment: don't let the lack of capital letters and brackets fool ya ;)

Comment: I was going to apply this to [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91023/smallest-palindrome-divisible-by-the-input), but `//.`will only try the replacements `65536` times. FYI

Comment: whoa! I wonder if there's a $-setting that can override that. But you're right—for example, my algorithm gives the wrong answer on input `65538!`.

Comment: What does "until it stops mattering" mean?

Comment: It repeatedly applies the rule to the expression until the expression no longer changes. For example, `240//.x/;EvenQ@x:>x/2` will repeatedly halve 240 to 120, 60, 30, 15 until the rule doesn't apply any more, and then stop, returning 15.

Comment: [Actually only 28436 digits](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/7/C1sfZ18EhKDEvPdXBzNTU2IIroCgzr8TBz8EnP93QwKG6QgcsrFjLlWZrqK@vVxGvb13xqGOxspVdhbahGlR5mkPF//8A).

Answer (score 16):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```js
f=(n,k)=>n%k?k:f(n,-~k)
```

*Note:* One interesting thing here is that the `k` parameter is initialized *ex nihilo* on the first iteration. This works because `n % undefined` is `NaN` (falsy as expected) and `-~undefined` equals `1`. On the next iterations, `-~k` is essentially equivalent to `k+1`.

#### Test

```js
f=(n,k)=>n%k?k:f(n,-~k)

// first 100 terms
for(i = 1, list = []; i <= 100; i++) {
  list.push(f(i));
}
console.log(list.join(' '));

// larger test cases
console.log(f(1234567));
console.log(f(12252240));
console.log(f(232792560));
```

Comment: Exactly what I got. I'd be surprised if anything shorter is possible

Comment: @ETHproductions On second thought, there's a shorter one. :-)

Comment: Um. That's... uh... wow.

Answer (score 15):

### Pyth, 3 bytes

```
f%Q
```

Basically, `f` loops the code until `%QT` (`Q % T` where `T` is the iteration variable) is true.

[Try it online here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%25Q&input=10&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20%0A21%0A22%0A23%0A24%0A25%0A26%0A27%0A28%0A29%0A30%0A31%0A32%0A33%0A34%0A35%0A36%0A37%0A38%0A39%0A40%0A41%0A42%0A43%0A44%0A45%0A46%0A47%0A48%0A49%0A50%0A51%0A52%0A53%0A54%0A55%0A56%0A57%0A58%0A59%0A60%0A61%0A62%0A63%0A64%0A65%0A66%0A67%0A68%0A69%0A70%0A71%0A72%0A73%0A74%0A75%0A76%0A77%0A78%0A79%0A80%0A81%0A82%0A83%0A84%0A85%0A86%0A87%0A88%0A89%0A90%0A91%0A92%0A93%0A94%0A95%0A96%0A97%0A98%0A99%0A100&debug=1)

Comment: Saw the problem, made this answer, came here to post it, found yours. Well done!

Comment: I wrote this and felt awesome about myself: `.V1In%Qb0bB`
Saw your answer, and not feeling so awesome anymore.

Comment: @JohnRed Lol, I think you just need to familiarize yourself with the built-ins in Pyth.

Answer (score 14):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 12 bytes

```
\\)?}'@{!%.}
```

Embiggened:

```
   \ \ )
  ? } ' @
 { ! % . }
  . . . .
   . . .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#@x8To2lfq@5QraiqV/v/v5GxkbmlkamZAQA)

Comment: That's a very impressive score for Hexagony, nice work!

Answer (score 13):

## Python, <strike>43</strike> <strike>36</strike> 35 bytes

```py
f=lambda n,d=2:d*(n%d>0)or f(n,d+1)
```

Answer (score 11):

## R, 28 bytes

Pretty straightforward, nothing fancy. Takes input from stdin, increments value `T` until `i` modulo `T` is nonzero.

```
i=scan()
while(!i%%T)T=T+1
T
```

If you want something a little more fancy, there's the following for **29 bytes**:

```
i=scan()
match(0,!i%%1:(i+1))
```

Explained:

> `i=scan()` : Read `i` from stdin.
>
> `1:(i+1)` : Generate all integers from `1` to `i+1` (the `+1` accounting for the cases of `1` and `2`).
>
> `i%%1:(i+1)` : Modulo the input by every number in our list.
>
> `!i%%1:(i+1)` : Negate the resulting list; this implicitly converts it to a logical type, such that `0` is `FALSE` and nonzero is `TRUE`. After negating, `TRUE` values become `FALSE` and vice-versa. Now, all originally nonzero values are coded as `FALSE`.
>
> `match(0,!i%%1:(i+1))` : Return the index of the first instance of `0` in our list. `0` is `FALSE`, so this returns the index of the first `FALSE` in the list, which is the first nonzero value from the modulo operation. Since our original list began at `1`, the index is equal to the value of the smallest non-divisor.

Comment: Nice, just wanted to suggest using `which.min`, but then I saw the edit and it seems `match` does a similar job.

Comment: Also, nice trick using `T`, saving the need to define it before the `while` loop.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Thanks! I can't find a way for the vectorized approach to be shorter than the `while` approach, which is fine as it's very memory-intensive for large N. The `T` trick is one of those treats which is great for golfing but absolutely horrible for actual programming. (And of course you can use `F` too when you need a `0`.)

Comment: You may save two bytes by using 0:i+1 instead of 1:(i+1) although I am not sure how it plays with the %% operator.

Comment: @antoine-sac Unfortunately, `%%` takes precedence over `+`, so parens are still necessary: `(0:i+1)`, with the same number of bytes as `1:(i+1)`. I actually had the former originally, but changed it to the latter as it's easier to read.

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell, 26 bytes

```haskell
f n=until((>0).mod n)(+1)1
```

Everyone forgets about `until`!

Answer (score 9):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
~{=#>:A'*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog#@19XbatsZ@WorlX7/7@Ryf8oAA)

This came out very similar to (but shorter than) Fatalize's original solution. Fatalize has since switched to a different algorithm that ties with this one via a different method, so I'm going to have to explain it myself:

```
~{=#>:A'*}
~{       }    inverse of the following function:
  =           try possible values for the input, if it's unbound
   #>         the input is a positive integer
     :A'*     there is no A for which the input times A is the output
```

When we invert the function, by swapping "input" and "output", we get a fairly reasonable algorithm (just expressed in an awkward way): "try possible positive integers, in their natural order (i.e. 1 upwards), until you find one that can't be multiplied by anything to produce the input". Brachylog doesn't do floating-point calculations unless all inputs are known, so it'll only consider integer A.

Comment: Never thought about doing that, that's neat!

Answer (score 9):

## COW, 174 bytes

```
oomMOOMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMmOomOoMoOMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMmOoMOOmoO
MOomoOMoOmOoMOOmoOmoomoOMOOmOoMoOmoOMOomoomOomOoMOOmOo
moomoOMOomoomoOmoOMOOmOomOomOomOoOOMOOOMOomOOmoomOomOo
mOomOomOomoo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cow#bYxBCgAxCAO/1FN/IXmJ5P8nN9pqLwtBwjAxSDfAzJw4yQ4qxh8uObsEXfEmziLAGbbD@6p4O7eMP0GCEoDZvpARe30)

This code is only partially my own -- it implements a [modulus algorithm that I ported from brainfuck.](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#Modulus_algorithm)  The rest of the code is my own.  However, since I did not write the modulus algorithm, I haven't truly investigated how it works and cannot document that part of the code.  Instead, I'll give my usual breakdown, followed by a more in-depth explanation of why the code works.

### Code breakdown

```
oom                          ;Read input into [0].
MOO                          ;Loop while [0].  We never change [0], so the program only terminates forcibly after a print.
  MMMmoOmoOmoOMMMmOomOo      ; Copy [0] to [3] and navigate to [1].
  MoOMMMmoOmoOmoOMMM         ; Increment [1], and copy it to [4]
  mOo                        ; Navigate back to [3].
  MOO                        ; Modulus algorithm.  Direct port of brainfuck algorithm.
    moOMOomoOMoOmOo
    MOO
      moO
    moo
    moO
    MOO
      mOoMoOmoOMOo
    moo
    mOomOo
    MOO
      mOo
    moo
    moOMOo
  moo                        ; End modulus algorithm.
  moOmoO                     ; Navigate to [5].  This contains our modulus.
  MOO                        ; Only perform these operations if [5] is non-zero -- i.e. [0] % [1] != 0
    mOomOomOomOoOOMOOOMOomOO ;  Navigate to [1], print its contents, then error out.
  moo                        ; End condition
  mOomOomOomOomOo            ; Since we're still running, [0] % [1] == 0, so navigate back to [0] and try again.
moo                          ;End main loop.
```

### Explanation

The code first reads the integer into [0].  Each iteration of the main loop (lines 2 through 26) increments [1], then copies everything necessary over to the modulus algorithm, which spits out its result into [5].  If [5] contains any value, then [1] is the number we need to print.  We print it, and then force-quit the program.

Since COW is a brainfuck derivative, it functions relatively similar to the way brainfuck operates -- infinite strip of tape, you can move left or right, increase or decrease, and "loop" while the current tape value is non-zero.  In addition to brainfuck, COW comes with a couple of useful features.

```
(0) moo -- Equivalent to ]
(1) mOo -- Equivalent to <
(2) moO -- Equivalent to >
(3) mOO -- No equivalent.  Evaluate current tape value as instruction from this list.
(4) Moo -- If tape is 0, equivalent to ,; if tape is non-zero, equivalent to .
(5) MOo -- Equivalent to -
(6) MoO -- Equivalent to +
(7) MOO -- Equivalent to [
(8) OOO -- No equivalent.  Set tape (positive or negative) to 0
(9) MMM -- No equivalent.  If register is empty, copy tape to register.  If register is non-empty, paste register to tape and clear register.
(10) OOM -- No equivalent.  Print an integer from tape to STDOUT
(11) oom -- No equivalent.  Read an integer from STDIN and store it on tape
```

The real point of interest here is instruction 3, `mOO`.  The interpreter reads the current tape value, and executes an instruction based on that tape value.  If the value is less than 0, greater than 11, or equal to 3, the interpreter terminates the program.  We can use this as a quick-and-dirty force quit of the main loop (and the program entirely) once we've found our non-divisor.  All we have to do is print our number, clear [1] (with `OOO`), decrement it to -1 with `MOo`, and then execute instruction -1 via `mOO` which ends the program.

The tape itself for this program functions as follows:

```
[0]  -- Read-in integer from STDIN.
[1]  -- Current divisor to test
[2]  -- Placeholder for modulus algorithm
[3]  -- Temporary copy of [0] for use for modulus algorithm
[4]  -- Temporary copy of [1] for use for modulus algorithm
[5]  -- Placeholder for modulus algorithm.  Location of remainder at end of loop.
[6]  -- Placeholder for modulus algorithm
[7]  -- Placeholder for modulus algorithm
```

The modulus algorithm naturally clears [2], [3], [6], and [7] at the end of the operation.  [4]'s contents get overwritten with the register paste on line 4, and [5] is zero when [0] is divisible by [1], so we don't have to clear it.  If [5] is non-zero, we force-quit on line 23 so we don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
,.=:?r'%0'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog#@6@jZ2tlX6SuaqD@/7@RsZG5pZGpmcH/KAA)

#### Explanation

```
,.=           Assign an integer to the output
 . :?r'%0     Input mod Output ≠ 0
        0'    Output ≠ 0
```

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
Xµ¹NÖ_½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x9xaOuhnX6Hp8Uf2vv/v5GxkbmlkamZAQA)

**Explanation**

```
Xµ       # run until counter is 1
  ¹      # push input
   N     # push iteration counter
    Ö_   # push input % iteration counter != 0
      ½  # if true, increase counter
         # output last iteration
```

Comment: Nice, I was wondering how you'd do this iteratively in 05AB1E.

Answer (score 7):

## C, <s>32</s> 35 bytes

```
i;f(x){for(i=1;x%++i<1;);return i;}
```

*Edit: added `i=1` in the loop*

#### Usage

```
main(c,v)char**v;{printf("%d",f(atoi(*++v)));}
```

#### Full Program version, 64 Bytes:

```
main(c,v)char**v;{*++v;for(c=1;atoi(*v)%++c<1;);printf("%d",c);}
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
1%@#Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2@o6qD8cMei////W5gYAAA)

Explanation:

```
1%@#Ḣ
1  #      Find the first … numbers, counting up from 1, such that
 %@       dividing those numbers into … gives a truthy remainder
    Ḣ     then return the first
```

This is a horrendous abuse of `#`; there are plenty of operators in this program, but a ton of missing operands. `#` really wants the `1` to be given explicitly for some reason (otherwise it tries to default to the input); however, everything else that isn't specified in the program defaults to the program's input. (So for example, if you give 24 as input, this program finds the first 24 numbers that don't divide 24, then returns the first; kind-of wasteful, but it works.)

Comment: Damn you Jelly! Pyth beats you today! :D

Comment: ASCII-only: `2%@1#`

Answer (score 6):

## C#, <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
n=>{int i=0;while(n%++i<1);return i;}
```

Saved two bytes thanks to Martin!

Comment: I like while(!(n%++i)); better but of course, this is code golf and 1 byte is 1 byte.

Comment: Does that work? I didn't know that the 0 evaluated to false automatically

Comment: Ah, I tried it in C++, yeah it doesn't work with C#.

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/MATLAB, <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```matlab
@(n)find(mod(n,1:n+1),1)
```

`find(...,1)` returns the index (`1`-based) of the first nonzero element of the vector in the first argument. The first argument is `[n mod 1, n mod 2, n mod 3, n mod 4,...,n mod (n+1)]` That means we have to add `+1` to the index, since we start testing at `1`. Thanks @Giuseppe for -2 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPMy0zL0UjNz9FI0/H0CpP21BTx1Dzf2JesYahkZGpkZGJgeZ/AA)

Comment: `@(n)find(mod(n,1:n+1),1)` is shorter, isn't it?

Comment: it is indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
ÌL¹ÑK¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@4x@fQzsMTvQ@t@f/fEAA)

Also, it spells "LINK!"... Kinda...

```
ÌL     # Push [1..n+2]
  ¹Ñ   # Push divisors of n.
    K¬ # Push a without characters of b, and take first item.
```

Comment: @Zgarb missed that part, initial increment by 2 fixes the problem.

Comment: Nice! I always forget that 05ab1e has a divisor function :)

Comment: I know this wasn't possible yet in the legacy version of 05AB1E, but it can be -1 now by using `∞` instead of `ÌL`. :) I've also just posted [an alternative 5-byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198337/52210).

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
‘ḍ€i0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYcbDHb2PmtZkGvz//9/IBAA)

#### How it works

```
‘ḍ€i0  Main link. Argument: n

‘      Increment; yield n+1.
 ḍ€    Divisible each; test 1, ..., n+1 for divisibility by n.
   i0  Find the first index of 0.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
%R;‘TḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@68aZP2oYUbIwx2L/v//b2QCAA)

Explanation:

```
                                               Assume 24 is our N
 R      Generate all numbers from 1 to N         [1, 2, 3, 4 .., 24]
  ;‘    Attach N+1 to that list (for cases 1,2)  [1, 2, 3, 4 .., 25]
%       And modulo-divide our input by it
        Yields a list with the remainder         [0, 0, 0, 0, 4 ...]
    T   Return all thruthy indexes               [5, 7, ...]
     Ḣ  Takes the first element of that list -->  5
```

Comment: I don't know Jelly, but could you save a byte by increasing N before you generate the range?

Comment: @Emigna I don't know Jelly either ;) I don't see how: incrementing it earlier also makes the modulo test against N+1, or increaes the remainders `[1, 1, 1, 1, 5, ...]`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought it might be possible to do N%range(1,N+1), but if it increases the N in both instances that's no good.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 19 bytes

18 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```pl
$_=$_%++$.?$.:redo
```

To run it:

```
perl -pE '$_=$_%++$.?$.:redo' <<< 12252240
```

*Not very detailed* explanations:
 - `$.` is a special variable whose default value is the current line number of the last filehandle accessed (stdin here), so after reading the first line of input, it's set to 1.
 - `$_` holds the input and is implicitly printed at the end (thanks to `-p` flag).
 - `redo` (in that context) considers that the program is in a loop and redo the current iteration (only `$.` will be different since it got incremented).
 - So if we found the smallest number (stored in `$.`) that doesn't divide `$_`, then we set `$_` to it, otherwise, we try the next number (thanks to `redo`).

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2.7.9, 32 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,d=1:n%d>0or-~f(n,d+1)
```

[Test on Ideone](http://ideone.com/G8KmqL)

Recursively counts up potential non-divisors `d`. It's shorter to recursively the increment the result than to output `d`. An offset of `1` is achieved by the Boolean of `True`, which equals `1`, but since `d==1` is always a divisor, the output is always converted to a number.

Python 2.7.9 is used to allow  allow `0or`. Versions starting 2.7.10 will attempt to parse `0or` as the start of an octal number and given a syntax error. [See this on Ideone](http://ideone.com/TJxNi8).

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 17 bytes

```perl6
{first $_%*,1..*}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25uLKrVRQS85PSVWw/V@dlllUXKKgEq@qpWOop6dV@784sVJBDyKdll@kkJOZl1r835DLiMvIhMvQyNjE1MwcSBuZGhmZGHAZGRuZWxqZmhkAAA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  # return the first value
  first

  # where the block's argument ｢$_｣ modulus the current value ｢*｣
  # doesn't return 0 ( WhateverCode lambda )
  $_ % *,
  # ( ｢$_ !%% *｣ would be the right way to write it )

  # from 1 to Whatever
  1 .. *
}
```

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcVLCoAgAAXAqzzCog9IvtSI0qtIi1wVRa0iOrs1mzmWc7Vpu1FEuPQ0pZJSipDX1ZtGXPONTAQ4jydChDdD3E9MCgQ1FDttbP9PQ@oW7NgPNLb16QM "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## julia, 28 bytes

```
N->findfirst(x->N%x>0,1:N+2)
```

Note: since `1:N+2` doesn't allocate memory there is no memory problems for large `N` s
- @flawr `N+2` save for me some bytes
- @Martin 's suggestion saved 1 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 7 bytes

```
;÷@uR-m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@299eLtDaZBu7v//RiYA) (note: this is a very slow solution, and will take a long time for large test cases)

Explanation:

```
;÷@uR-m
;÷       duplicate N, divisors
  @uR    range(1, N+2)
     -   set difference (values in [1, N+1] that are not divisors of N)
      m  minimum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

```hs
f n=[k|k<-[2..],mod n k>0]!!0
```

The expression `[k|k<-[2..]]` just creates an infinite list `[2,3,4,5,...]`. With the condition `mod n k>0` we only allow those `k` in the list that do not divide `n`. Appending `!!0` just returns the first entry (the entry at index `0`) form that list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mkGcbnV2TbaMbbaSnF6uTm5@ikKeQbWcQq6ho8D83MTNPwVahoLQkuKTIJ0@lOCO/XCVNwdDIyNTIyMTgPwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 8 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
1⍳⍨0≠⍳|⊢
```

`1⍳⍨` position of first True in

`0≠` the non-zero values of

`⍳|` the division remainders of 1...**N** when divided by

`⊢` **N**

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u21901%u2373%u23680%u2260%u2373%7C%u22A2%20%u22C4%20f%A8%u2373100&run)

Note: this works for 1 and 2 because `1⍳⍨` returns 1 + the length of its argument if none is found.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 30 bytes

```
for(;$argv[1]%++$i<1;);echo$i;
```

if run from console with `-r` option (thx to @ais523)

```
php -r 'for(;$argv[1]%++$i<1;);echo$i;' 232792560
```

## 32 bytes

```
<?for(;$argv[1]%++$i<1;);echo$i;
```

thanks to @manatwork for removing 1 byte

## 33 bytes (original)

```
<?for(;$argv[1]%++$i==0;);echo$i;
```

Comment: IIRC, the `<?` doesn't have to be part of your byte count (because PHP has a command-line mode that doesn't require it).

Comment: The old trick: compare against `<1` instead of `==0`.

Comment: Dang. I reached to `for(;!($argv[1]%$i);$i++);echo$i;`. Yours is the natural evolution of mine. This has my upvote!

Answer (score 3):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 14 bytes

```
:[a+1|~a%b|_Xb
```

Explanation:

```
:      Read the first cmd line param as a number, called 'a'
[a+1|  FOR (b=1 ; b <= a+1; b++) <-- a+1 for cases a = 1 or 2
~a%b   IF A modulo B ( == 0, implicit)
|_Xb   THEN exit the program, printing b
       [IF and FOR implicitly closed by QBIC]
```

Answer (score 3):

## C, 30 bytes

Recursion is your friend:

```
f(x,i){return x%i?i:f(x,i+1);}
```

Call as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

f(x,i){return x%i?i:f(x,i+1);}

int main() {
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("f(%d, 1) = %d\n", i, f(i, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you have your ternary operator backwards. `x%i?i:f(x,i+1)` will call `f(x,i+1)` when `x` is NOT divisible by `i` instead of when it is.

Comment: @RobertBenson When `x` is divisible by `i`, `x%i` produces the value zero, which is interpreted as false by C, so `f(x,i+1)` gets called. Thus, the recursion happens as long as `x` is divisible by `i`, just as it should. But I agree, this ternary expression is mind-screwing: I wrote it the wrong way round at the first try myself...

Comment: That's what I get for looking at these things while I'm trying to dig through `FORTRAN` code at work. Also... I might have looked at a different question just before looking at your answer... yeah... I'll use that as my excuse. :)  Nice work.

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
I2/L/);?%<@O
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to MickyT.

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=STIvTC8pOz8lPEBP&input=NDI=&speed=5)

#### Explanation

In cube form, the code is:

```
    I 2
    / L
/ ) ; ? % < @ O
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

Basically, this just takes the input and starts a counter.  It then checks each successive value of the counter until it finds one that isn't a factor of the input.

Comment: `I2/L/);?%<@O` for a couple of bytes less.  Same general process, just different path

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```rust
|n|(1..).find(|x|x%n>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZnZNaopBmlZanUWpspKlrF2/7vyavRsNQT09TLy0zL0WjpqKmQjXPzkDzvzVXYnFxalFJfGqhokaahqGmTnB@bqqGkaYmmowFVMYYJFP7HwA)

A closure that iterates over all positive integers returning `Some(n)` where n is the first integer modulo input is greater than zero.

Answer (score 3):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), <sup>20</sup> 18 bytes

*-2 thanks to Jo King!*

```
 >!/|!`!}
{"^."^[1
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiID4hL3whYCF9XG57XCJeLlwiXlsxIiwidiI6MSwiaSI6IjI0In0=)

[image: run for 24]

The values follow the arrow heads. `{` gets the `N`, here 24. This value is `"` duplicated and both values are then merged into `!`: repeat 24 for 24 times. The 24s go the right, while their indices are pushed down. Then `index | 24` (mod) is calculated (for dividers this is 0). We repeat the corresponding index for `i | 24` times, thus dividers get deleted. 5 on the other hand will be repeated 5 times. As we only want 1 of them, we take `!` only 1 of them. The rest of the values build up and when nothing moves, the factory comes to a halt. [Here is an ungolfed variant.](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiID4hPi8uPnZcbntcIl4gXCI+Pnw+diAgXG4gICAgPj4+Pj4hYD4hPn1cbiAgICAgICAgICAgWzEiLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiMTIifQ==)

Answer (score 2):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 15 +3 = 18 bytes

```
1\n;
?\1+:{:}$%
```

Input is expected to be on the stack at program start, so +3 bytes for the `-v` flag. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@28Yk2fNZR9jqG1VbVWrovr//3/dMgVDIyNTIyMTAwA)

Answer (score 2):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
p\~~|1
 >i
```

Takes input from STDIN and outputs to STDOUT.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jellyfish#@18QU1dXY8ilYJf5/7@RsZG5pZGpmQEA)

Martin Ender saved 2 bytes, thanks!

### Explanation

```
 \~~|
 >i
```

This part is one function that uses the input value in its definition.

```
   ~|
```

This `~`-cell is given a function, so it flips its arguments: its produces the binary function "left argument modulo (`|`) right argument".
The built-in modulo function in Jellyfish takes its arguments in the reverse order.

```
  ~~|
  i
```

This `~`-cell is given a value and a function, so it does partial application: it produces the binary function "input (`i`) modulo right argument".
Let's call that function **f**.

```
 \~~|
 >i
```

The `\`-cell is given two functions, so it does iteration: it produces the unary function "increment (`>`) until the function **f** applied to previous and current values gives a truthy (nonzero) result, then return current value".
This means that the argument is incremented until it doesn't divide the input.

```
p\~~|1
 >i
```

Finally, we apply this function to the initial value `1` and print the result with `p`.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
1D.f%
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=1D.f%25&input=3&warnings=0)

```
1D.f  - first number after 1 where
    % -  i%input != 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Beeswax](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl), 19 bytes

```
 >~P~q
{~b"%g<~1fT_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/beeswax#@69gVxdQV8hVXZekpJpuU2eYFhL//7@hkZGpkZGJwX8A)

Example, using `3` as value

```
                  lstack     gstack  print
           _      [0,0,0]    []            create bee
          T       [0,0,3]                  enter number
         f                   [3]           push top lstack value on gstack
        1         [0,0,1]                  push 1 on lstack
       ~          [0,1,0]                  swap lstack 1st and 2nd
     g<           [0,1,3]                  push gstack 1st on lstack
    %             [0,1,0]                  lstack 1st = 1st % 2nd
   "                                       if lstack 1st > 0 skip next, else don’t skip
  b                                        redirect to upper left
 >                                         redirect to right
  ~               [0,0,1]                  swap lstack 1st and 2nd
   P              [0,0,2]                  increment lstack 1st
    ~             [0,2,0]                  swap lstack 1st and 2nd
     q                                     redirect to lower right
      <                                    redirect to left
     g            [0,2,3]                  push gstack 1st on lstack
    %             [0,2,1]                  lstack 1st = 1st % 2nd
   "                                       lstack 1st > 0 → skip next
 ~                [0,1,2]                  swap lstack 1st and 2nd
{                                    "2"   print lstack 1st to STDOUT
                                           end program
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 44 + 2 = 46 bytes

```
int m(int x,int y){return x%++y>0?y:m(x,y);}
```

Recursive solution which requires an extra `,1` when calling. Call with `m(x,1)`.

Comment: Is the +2 for the parameter required? I use a recursive method as well sometimes, but usually I haven't included the parameter input (usually `0` or `1`) in the byte-count. Is there a rule for this?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It's outside of a standard call, so yes, I would consider it necessary. I do not know if there is any "rule" for this, but this is the fair-play method as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 17 bytes

Absolutely genius to use the input as upper bound for for loop?

```
For(I,1,Ans
If not(fPart(Ans/I
End
I
```

Comment: `Ans` is not an [allowed I/O method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8580/45941).

Comment: According to who?

Comment: That didn't work when I tested with 24.

Comment: @kamoroso94 Thanks for pointing that out, I had mistakenly put `I/Ans` instead of `Ans/I` but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

```
@uX}a
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QHVYfWE=&input=MjQ=)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby (C implementation), 26 bytes

```
->n{-(~n...0).min{|x|n%x}}
```

Explanation: `~n` 2s-complement-bitwise-negates n, so it's equivalent for positive n to `-(n+1)`. Let's work through with n=6. We generate a range from -7 to 0, excluding 0, and then find the minimum of that range using a custom comparison function. `min` expects a block that takes two arguments and returns a negative number if the first one is smaller, 0 if they're the same, and 1 if the first one is larger. Here, we're implicitly telling the block to ignore the second argument, so `x` is just the first element in the comparison. The block will return zero when x is the negation of a factor of n: in our n=6 example, `6%-3` is `0`. When it's not, it'll be a negative number: `6%-4` is `-2`.

So as Ruby iterates through the range, it'll do this: -7 is the first candidate for a minimum. Is -6 less than it? It passes -6 (x) and -7 (ignored) into the block, and the block returns 0 (since 6 is a factor of 6), so no. Is -5 less than it? It passes -5 in to the block and it returns a negative number, so yes. So the current candidate is -5. Is -4 less than -5? The block says yes. -3, -2, and -1 all get 0s, so -4 wins.

Finally we negate the result to get 4.

I'm calling this implementation-dependent since the Ruby spec would allow the sorting to be done differently, although my guess is most implementations do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
←`-NḊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7vbGSam1/8qKnx4Y7FhgYG/x@1TUjQ9Xu4o@v/fwA) The testing code prints the output for the first 100 terms. Note that the function runs in time proportional to the input value; the `1234567` case takes about 12 seconds on my machine.

Comment: [Alternative 5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyxB9VHjBr////8bGhmbmJqZAwA "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 5 bytes

```
?Ḋ¬)ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwiP+G4isKsKeG5hSIsIiIsIjIzMjc5MjU2MCJd)

Or

## 5 bytes

```
₌ɾKFh
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigozJvktGaCIsIiIsIjIzMjc5MjU2MCJd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$10\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 8.231 bytes

```
[FJkxxG@}1
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJbRkpreHhHQH0xIiwiMjQiXQ==)

```
   k        # Get the factors of
    x       # the input,
  J         # then append
     x      # the input to that (k doesn't include it).
 F          # Filter out anything in that list from:
      G     #   an infinite list
       1    #   starting at 1
        @}  #   incrementing each time.
[           # Get the first item from that.
```

Comment: Trailing `x`s can always be removed.

Comment: @Steffan Oh, true

Comment: "In particular, make sure that your answer works for inputs 1 and 2"

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Oops, missed that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
&:1>:00p%v
g1+^@.g00_:00
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=JjoxPjowMHAldgpnMSteQC5nMDBfOjAw&input=MjMyNzkyNTYw)

**Explanation**

```
&                 Read N from stdin.
 :                Save a duplicate copy.
  1               Push initial test divisor, D.

   >              Main loop starts here.
    :00p          Save a copy of the current D.
        %v        Calculate N modulo D and move down.
         _        If not zero (i.e. N is not divisible by D), then break to the left.
          :       Otherwise continue to the right and prepare another copy of N.
g          00     Retrieve the previously saved D (wrapping to the beginning of the line).
 1+               Increment D.
   ^              Repeat the loop again.

         _        We break out of the loop going left.
      g00         Retrieve the last value of D.
    @.            Write it to stdout and exit.
```

Thanks to [Mistah Figgins](/users/62574/mistah-figgins) for saving me a byte.

Comment: I believe you can shorten this by getting rid of the `!`. You would need to change the second line to `g1+^@.g00_:00` (switching the direction of the 2 branches)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 36 Bytes

Immediates window function; Takes input from cell `A1` and prints to the Immediates window.

```vb
i=2:While([A1]Mod i=0):i=i+1:Wend:?i
```

Comment: Save 1 byte by deleting the space between `[A1]` and `mod`

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
t:\f1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@19iFZNmqPn/v6GRkamRkYkBAA)

Comment: You need `Q` after `t` so that it works for inputs `1` and `2`

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>54</s> <s>51</s> <s>49</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes

Golfed:

```
int m(int x){int i=1;for(;x%++i<1;);return i;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int m(int x)
{
    int i = 1;
    for (; x % ++i < 1;);
    return i;
}
```

Nothing fancy... I did try with a `while(1>0)` loop, was 2 bytes longer

Comment: @Henry Pointed out in an attempted edit that you have extra whitespace in your if statement.  It seems `x % i > 0` can be replaced with `x%i>0`.

Comment: 47 bytes: `int n(int x){int y=1;for(;x%++y==0;);return y;}`

Comment: For future reference (it doesn't really help here, but still), you don't need the for-loop brackets when using a single if statement followed by a function (so `for(;;)if(true)x();` would work), and you can use `for(;;)` instead of `while(1>0)`.

Comment: @peech You can use my solution in the comment two above this, you know. ;) Shaves off another two bytes.

Comment: yeah i know, but i dont want to take credit for your solution :) you should post it, there's no limitation for one solution per each language :)

Comment: @peech My solution isn't significantly different enough to post it separately. :P Please, use it.

Comment: hehe ok, thank u very much :)

Comment: instead `i==0` write `i<1`

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 48 Bytes

```
(defn f[n](some #(if(>(mod n %)0)%)(range 1 n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 26 bytes

```powershell
for(;!("$args"%++$i)){};$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@5@WX6RhraihpJJYlF6spKqtrZKpqVlda62S@f//fyMTAA)

Comment: Other solutions have switched from `!()` to `<1`, would that help here too?

Comment: @Neil powershell uses bash-style operators, so it would end up being `-lt1` (or `-eq0`), one byte longer unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 28 bytes

```
.+
$*11
(1+?)(?!1\1*$).*
$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/ivp82lomVoyKVhqG2vqWGvaBhjqKWiqafFpaJn@P@/IZcRlzGXkQmXoZGxiamZOQA)

Thanks to Martin for 6 bytes!

In the first stage we generate `N + 1` 1s. Then we find the smallest number of ones such that we cannot fit that number evenly into `N` by hard-coding the offset by one that we introduced in the first step. This offsetting is used to allow 1 and 2 to work.

Answer (score 1):

### [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/), 8 bytes

```
U%°V?V:ß
```

This was inspired by [Arnauld's solution.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105432/61613)

Thanks ETHproductions for golfing this even more!

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@x@qGmYfZnV4fqiObl3Y//9GxkbmlkamZgYA)

Comment: I just realized that `V` defaults to 0, which allows you to do `U%°V?V:ßUV` (`°` is `++`). Then you can take advantage of the fact that `ß` passes in U and V by default to do `U%°V?V:ß` for only 8 bytes :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions Wow, very nice!

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 21 bytes

```
?sn1[1+dlnr%0=b]dsbxp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@29fnGcYbaidkpNXpGpgmxSbUpxUUfD/v5EJAA)

The program works by running through all integers starting with 2 until it finds one that isn't a divisor of the input.  The input is kept in register n, and the current number being tested as a divisor/non-divisor is on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

## REXX, 35 bytes

```
arg a
do n=1 until a//n>0
end
say n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>25 29</strike> 27 bytes

```
{for(i=0;!($1%++i););$0=i}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCPT1sBaUUPFUFVbO1PTWtNaxcA2s9bw/39DI2MTUzNzBSAw4jI0MjI1MjIxAHIMLbmMjI3MLY1MzYBcI2MA)

Can save 3 bytes by leaving out the `i=0` but then multi-line input would be incorrect.

As with all `AWK` scripts, the code can be placed in a file or typed in at the command line.

Command Line Usage:

```
awk '{for(i=0;!($1%++i););$0=i}1' <<< inputNumber
```

or place numbers in a FILE each on its own line and do:

```
awk '{for(i=0;!($1%++i););$0=i}1' FILE
```

Two bytes saved by converting to `for` loop, also added TIO link.

Comment: In the case of an input file with numbers, only the first result is always correct. The following results give the smallest number that doesn't divide the given number *and is greater than the previous result*, because `i` is not reinitialized.

Comment: Good catch. I can fix it by adding 4 bytes :(

Comment: I'm not sure if it needed to be fixed, or if it's enough to not claim that it works with more than one number. A function must be usable more than once, but I think one could argue that here we have a whole program, and giving more than one number is illegal input.

Comment: @ChristianSievers I feel bad enough writing code I consider inefficient... to make something that can't be called sequentially in `AWK` would make me feel truly dirty. :p

Comment: I feel you. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 28 bytes

```
->n{(1..n+1).find{|x|n%x>0}}
```

Comment: @GB yep, my bad. I foobed in the golfing stage.

Answer (score 1):

Perl, 25 bytes

```
sub{1 until$_[0]%++$i;$i}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 49 bytes

```
readIO
lbla
x+1
b=i
b%x
a=1
a-b
if a a
printInt x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@1@Umpji6c@Vk5STyFWhbciVZJvJlaRawZVoa8iVqJvElZmmkKiQyFVQlJlX4plXolDx//9/I2Mjc0sjUzMDAA)

Fairly simple. I was confused for a little while.

Answer (score 1):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 13 bytes

```
+:#
" %#!
?:;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/labyrinth#@69tpcylpKCqrMhlb2X9/7@RCQA)

#### Explanation

To avoid shifting around too many values to keep track of both the input and the current potential divisor, we're storing the latter implicitly as the stack depth by creating copies of the input. The 3x3 block on the left is the main loop. The first iteration doesn't really do anything, but it helps with the overall layout to delay reading the input until later.

```
+   Add top two stack elements. Does nothing on the first two iterations,
    but removes a zero on subsequent iterations.
:   Duplicate. Does nothing on the first iteration, but copies the input
    later on.
#   Push the stack depth. 2 on the first two iterations, increasingly larger
    values later on.
%   Modulo. Gives zero on the first iteration, and acts as the trial division
    later on. If this is positive, the loop is exited.
;   Discard the zero.
:   Duplicate a zero on the first iteration, the input on subsequent iterations,
    increasing the stack depth.
?   Read input on first iteration, push zero later on.
```

Once `%` gives a positive value, we've found a non-divisor of the input. `#` pushes the stack depth once more, `!` prints it. Then the IP hits a dead and turns around. Now `#%` will leave the top of the stack unchanged (and positive), so the IP now enters the 3x3 main loop in counter-clockwise order. `#:+` pushes twice the stack depth but that's irrelevant. `?:;` all together push a single zero so that the `%` now terminates the program due to a division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 46 bytes

```
INPUT N
FOR I=2TO N+1
IF N MOD I THEN ?I:Q
NEXT
```

I hope that triggering an error to end the program is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 74 bytes

```
➡️i 10ii➕1ii
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f9h/oRuhQ/zZzUBid52EHfah/lTFj2at/D9jn6QOEgYiNdlKhgCJRo/zJ8x2wAovg6ocmomXPLRvKmGIF4nEPeBGf9BBBfXh/n9jWCjuRSA1IwGIDFlIYhYpGBkomBowAVWCwA)

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc) 30 bytes

```
i;f(n){for(i=0;n%++i<1;);i=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY2xCsMgFAD3fEUQhCe2oC8xoVj/pEuxWN5QG1I7Bb/darZCllsO7vz56X0pZANEsYX3CuSUjVxKumorLDmyubzuFEFs3bJSTAEYf9wiOwXQOIxmmoWwBwoN4qiOHA44X9BMu9yfMfXtW5@qUsr6ogDE0TinxPJNH2Dsr9S3EEndErnL5Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 31 bytes

```forth
: f 1 begin 1+ 2dup mod until ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRgqJKWmZ@YpGGorGKWUFijk5qcolOaVZOYoWP83NDIyNTIyMVAASegpAFXrKSQXcRkZG5lbGpmawcShwv8B)

#### Explanation

```forth
 1        \ place a 1 on the stack (divisor)
 begin    \ start an indefinite loop
 1+       \ add 1 to the divisor
 2dup     \ duplicate the top 2 stack items (n and divisor)
 mod      \ get n%divisor and place it on top of the stack
 until    \ end the loop when the top of the stack is anything other than 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 12 + 3 = 15 bytes

```
:l%?v:
;nll<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3ypH1b7Miss6LyfH5v///7plhkZGpkZGJgYA)

Takes input via the `-v` flag. Uses the length of the stack as a counter to check the divisibility of the number.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞Ö0k>
```

Bugfix thanks to *@Grimmy* (for `n=1`) at no additional byte-cost, so it can be undeleted again.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8w9MMsu3@/zcyNjK3NDI1MwAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/0cd8w5PM8i2@6/zP9pQx0jHWMfIRMfQyNjE1MwcSBuZGhmZGOgYGRuZWxqZmhnEAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞      # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 Ö     # Check for each whether it evenly divides the (implicit) input-integer
  0k   # Get the first (0-based) index of 0 in this list of 0s/1s
    >  # Increase this index by 1 to make it 1-based
       # (after which this is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 13 bytes

```perl6
{+(1...$_%*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WlvDUE9PTyVeVUuz9n9xYqWCHlA8Lb9IISczL7X4vyGXEZeRCZehkbGJqZk5kDYyNTIyMeAyMjYytzQyNTMAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 15 bytes

```
~:x;1{).x\%!}do
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v86qwtqwWlOvIkZVsTYl//9/I2Mjc0sjUzMDAA)

```
~:x;              # Store the input in the variable x
    1             # Push 1
     {     !}do   # While it is zero
      )           # Go to the next number
       .x\%       # x mod the current number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,i=1:i if x%i!=0else f(x,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRoUIn09bQKlMhM02hQjVT0dYgNac4VSFNAyiubaj5v6AoM69EI03DyERT8z8A)

This function just returns the second argument if it's a valid answer, and calls itself with an incremented second argument otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! I've edited in a link to an online testing environment so that others can test and run your code. You can save 2 bytes by removing the `!=0` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRoUIn09bQKlMhM02hQjVTITWnOFUhTQMoqm2o@b@gKDOvRCNNw8hEU/M/AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")) and be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) page for more ways you could golf your answer.

Comment: I got it down to 36, but how is left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
１Ｗ╵╶┌％！｝
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjExJXVGRjM3JXUyNTc1JXUyNTc2JXUyNTBDJXVGRjA1JXVGRjAxJXVGRjVE,i=MTIyNTIyNDA_,v=8)

###### Explanation:

```
1W╵╶┌%!} | Explanation             | Stack Visualization (of first iteration)
---------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------
1        | Push 1                  | 1
 W     } | Do ...                  | 1
  ╵      |  Increment ToS          | 2
   ╶     |  Push input             | 2, <input>
    ┌    |  Duplicate 2nd from top | 2, <input>, 2
     %!  |  Divides?               | 2, <0/1>
       } | ... while POP is truthy | <output>
         | Print ToS (implicit)    |
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ƙ%
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU5OCUyNSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTI0JmZsYWdzPQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
Ƙ%  # Implicit input
Ƙ   # First integer (starting from 1) where the following is truthy:
 %  #  The (implicit) input mod the number
    #  (this is nonzero/truthy iff the input isn't divisible by the number)
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), <s>27</s> 20 bytes

```lua
(range(2,n+9)&n%x)/z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/1@jKDEvPVXDSCdP21JTLU@1QlO/6v///0YmAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 20 bytes

```
/O
\M@/1!w.?h!?%n$K?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fnyvG10HfULFczz5D0V41T8Xb/v///4ZGBgA)

```
M1!w.?h!?%n$K?O@ # full program
M                # read one argument and put it on the stack
 1!              # save 1 on the tape
   w      n$K    # while loop, until the modulus is not 0
    .            # duplicate the input
     ?h!         # get the number on the tape, increase it and update the tape
        ?%       # pops the input and the number on the tape, push the modulus
             ?O@ # print the last number on the tape, the first number that does not divide the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 29 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 3.625 bytes

```
?%)ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJyPSIsIiIsIj8lKeG5hSIsIiIsIjEwMCJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 9 bytes

`#ä2+º%Ì1@`

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=I-QyK7olzDFA&in=MjQ=)

### Explanation

```
#         ; get an integer N from standard input
 ä2+º     ; push the range from zero to N+1
     %    ; vectorized remainder
      Ì   ; get indices of non-zero elements (zero-indexed)
       1@ ; get 2nd element (mod 0 is always non-zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 3 bytes (6 nibbles)

```
/|,~%@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWy_RrdOpUHSAcqNiC7YZcRlzGXCZcplxmXOZcFlyWXIYGXEYmEGkA)

I'm always amazed that Nibbles is able to 'fold-from-right' over an infinite list...

```
/|,~%@      # full program
/|,~%@$$    # with implicit variables added
 |          # filter
  .         # 1..
   ~        #    infinity
            # by truthy result of
     @      # input
    %       # modulo
      $     # it;
/           # then, fold from right
       $    # returning left element each time
            # (so: return left-most element)
```

Answer (score 0):

### C 70 bytes

```
 s(int *n){ int f=1;for(f=1;f<(*n);f++){if((*n)%f!=0)return f;}return f;}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 52 bytes

```
(let p((n 2))(cond[(= 0(modulo m n))(p(+ 1 n))][n]))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f m)
  (let loop ((n 2))
    (cond
      [(= 0 (modulo m n))
       (loop (+ 1 n))]
      [else n])))
```

Testing:

```
(f 24)
(f 1234567)
(f 12252240)
(f 232792560)
```

Output:

```
5
2
19
23
```

Answer (score 0):

## bash, 37 bytes

```
(($1%${2-1}))&&echo $2||$0 $1 $[$2+1]
```

Save the program in a file. Run it from the command line with the input number N as an argument:

*scriptname* N

Comment: `(($1%($2)))&&bc<<<$2||$0 $1 $2+1`   to be run as `scriptname N 2`

Comment: @izabera I like the idea of using bc, but I can't get it to be any shorter than the original 37 bytes without the contrivance of passing the extra argument 2.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 53 bytes

```
@set/ad=%2+1,r=%1%%d
@if %r%==0 %0 %1 %d%
@echo %d%
```

Well I beat Java anyway... Explanation:

- `set /a d = %2 + 1` This takes the second argument and adds 1. Of course, normally there is no second argument, but that's no problem, you just get `+1`, which is still a legal expression.
- `set /a r = %1 %% d` Since `%` is the argument/variable modifier, we need to double it to flag it as the remainder operator.
- `%0 %1 %d%` This is a form of tail recursion. `%0` refers to the batch file itself, `%1` is the original parameter and `%d%` is our loop variable, becoming `%2` in the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

## [DUP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 23 bytes (21 chars)

DUP is a derivative of FALSE, with a [similar solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105528/39407).

```
1[[^^/%0=][1+]#.]⇒a\a
```

Insert the value to be tested between the first `a` and the `\`, like this:

```
1[[^^/%0=][1+]#.]⇒a1234567\a
```

Explanation:

```
                         data
                         stack
1                        [1]                PUSH 1 on data stack
 [              ]⇒a                         define operator a
                   n     [1,n]              PUSH integer n on data stack
                    \    [n,1]              SWAP
                     a                      execute operator a
1[[^^/%0=][1+]#.]⇒a1234567\a
  [      ][  ]#                             while loop: while first block true,
                                                        execute second block
  [               ~1~
   ^                     [n,1,n]            OVER
    ^                    [n,1,n,1]          OVER
     /                   [n,1,n%1,n/1]      MODDIV: computes mod and division
      %                  [n,1,n%1]          POP
       0                 [n,1,n%1,0]        PUSH 0
        =                [n,1,true/false]   n%1 == 0 ?
         ]                                  if false (0), continue at ~2~
                                            if true (-1), execute next block
          [
           1             [n,1,1]            PUSH 1
            +            [n,2]              ADD
             ]#                             return to ~1~
               .  ~2~    [n]                print number to STDOUT
                                            exit operator a, end program
```

Try it out [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html).

Or clone [my DUP GitHub repository](https://github.com/m-lohmann/DUPEsolang.jl) for a DUP interpreter written in Julia, with full documentation.

Answer (score 0):

## [FALSE](http://esolangs.org/wiki/FALSE), 32 bytes

This FALSE solution is similar to the [DUP solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105523/39407) because DUP is a dialect of FALSE with some extra abilities.

```
1[[\$@$@$@$@\/*-0=][1+]#.]a:\a;!
```

In contrast to DUP, FALSE lacks the convenient MOD,DIV operator that computes both the MOD and DIV of two numbers at one time. FALSE only offers an integer division operator `/`. FALSE also does not offer the convenient OVER operator, and using the PICK `1ø` operator combo instead costs 3 bytes each. So, the solution above is actually the cheapest way to implement the OVER and MOD operators in FALSE.

Insert the value to be tested between the `:` and the `\`, like this:

```
1[[\$@$@$@$@\/*-0=][1+]#.]a:1234567\a;!
```

Explanation:

```
1[[\$@$@$@$@\/*-0=][1+]#.]a:n\a;!   (n marks the number)

1                                 [1]               PUSH 1 (counter c)
 [                       ]a:                        define function a
                            n     [1,n]             PUSH n
                             \    [n,1]             SWAP
                              a;!                   fetch address of a, execute a
  [               ][ ]#                             while loop while 1st block true,
                                                                execute 2nd block
   \                       ~1~    [1,n]             SWAP
    $                                               DUP
     @                                              ROT
      $@$@$@                      [n,1,n,1,n,1]     DUP,ROT,DUP,ROT,DUP,ROT,SWAP
                                                    (create 2 duplicates of the pair)
            /                     [n,1,n,1,n/1=n]   DIV
             *                    [n,1,n,1*n]       MUL
              -                   [n,1,n-n=0]       SUB
               0                  [n,1,0,0]         PUSH 0
                =                 [n,1,-1]          if 0==0 PUSH true(-1),
                                                    else push false (0)
                                                    if true, execute next block,
                                                    if false, continue at ~2~
                 ]
                  [1+]#           [n,2]             PUSH 1, ADD, (increment c),
                                                    loop back to ~1~
                  
                       .  ~2~     [n,c]             print integer c (top stack value) to STDOUT
```

Try it out [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/false-js.html).

Comment: You can remove the function definition/call entirely: `1[\$@$@$@$@\/*-0=][1+]#.` to get 24 bytes. (insert the value to test at the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab, 45 Bytes

```
function x=n(a)
x=2;while(~mod(a,x))x=x+1;end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 17 bytes

```
V2v[VvDD1+v{M(x&]
```

The output is the exit code of this program. Assuming that less that `LCM(Range(1,128))` is acceptable range.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/vitsy#@x9mVBYdVubiYqhdVu2rUaEW@///fyNjI3NLI1MzAwA)

#### Explanation:

Let `[...]` at the end of the line signify the state of the stack at that line.

```
V2v[VvDD1+v{M(x&]
V                 Capture the input as a final global variable (FGV).
 2v               Save 2 as a temporary variable.
   [            ] Repeat the item in brackets forever.
    V             Push the FGV to the stack.
     v            Dump the temporary variable (TV) to the stack. (call it "x")
      DD          Duplicate twice. The stack looks like [FGV, x, x, x].
        1+        Add one to the top value. [FGV, x, x, x+1]
          v       Capture the top value as the new temp var. (TV = x+1) [FGV, x, x]
           {      Rotate the top to the bottom of the stack. [x, FGV, x]
            M     Pop the top two values, push second-to-top mod top. [x, FGV%x]
             (    Pop the top value. If it is zero, then... [x]
              x   Pop the top value and exit with that exit code. []
               &  Enter a new stack. (Reset the stack).
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 37 bytes

```
n->{int i=1;while(n%++i<1);return i;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 33 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>(1 to n+1)find(n%_>0)get
```

Straightforwardly constructs a `Range` that covers the possible answers, finds the first one that is an answer, and gets it from the `Option`, knowing that it must exist.

Answer (score 0):

## C++ 55 Bytes

```
start: while(n%i>0) {;goto end;} i++; goto start; end:;
```

The while loop checks whether the number(input given by the user) is divisible by i(here the divisor  which is continuously increasing).

The entire code is

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n,i=1;
cout<<"Enter A Number";
cin>>n;
start:
while(n%i>0)
{
cout<<"The lowest integer that does not divide "<<n<<" is "<<i;
goto end;
}
   i++;
goto start;
  end:
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need all that whitespace, and you can easily save bytes by using shorter identifiers than `end` and `start`. On the other hand, you do need to submit either a full program or a function (not a snippet, like you have there), and you current demonstration code is way too long to really serve that role. (I also think you're using rather more verbose control constructs than you need to; in the C family, `for` is normally best for loops in [tag:code-golf] because it's fairly flexible and it has the shortest name.)

Answer (score 0):

**Q/KDB+ 36 Bytes**

```
f:{$[0=(y%x)mod 1;f[x+1;y];x]}
f[1;n]
```

**Description:**
Function f

```
f:{$[0=(y%x)mod 1;f[x+1;y];x]}
```

which consists of a conditional

```
$[0=(y%x)mod 1;f[x+1;y];x]
```

The conditional has 3 statements, each separated by a semi colon.

```
0=(y%x)mod 1  //y divided by x, mod 1 to determine if it is a decimal or not.
f[x+1;y]      //If it is not a decimal, call the function again and increment x.
x             //If it is a decimal, return x (as it doesn't divide n evenly.
```

To call the function:

```
f[1;n]
```

Start at 1 and pass in the value of n.

Answer (score 0):

## GameMaker Language, 58 bytes

```
a=argument0 for(i=1;i<=a;i++){if a mod i return i}return i
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 90 bytes

Horribly long, but I like how it reads ungolfed.

```clj
#(apply min(remove(into #{}(filter(fn[m](=(rem % m)0))(range 1(+ % 1))))(range 2(+ % 2))))
```

I probably have a lot of room to golf this given this was a totally naïve attempt at an algorithm.

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn smallest [n]
  (let [mults (into #{} (filter (fn [m] (= (rem n m) 0)) (range 1 (+ n 1))))] ; Find multiples, and place in a set for membership lookup
    (apply min ; Find minimum non-multiple
      (remove mults ; Remove multiples from the range 2 to (n+2)
              (range 2 (+ n 2))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## FALSE, <s>22</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
1[$$3ø\/*2ø=][1+]#
```

This is a modified version of the other FALSE answer (which is itself a modified version of the DUP answer)

```
1[[\$@$@$@$@\/*-0=][1+]#.]a:\a;!
```

First, of course, we can remove that function definition/call, as well as outputting the number to the stack instead of printing:

```
1[\$@$@$@$@\/*-0=][1+]#
```

`\$@$@$@$@\` is used to create 2 copies of the top 2 values on the stack `{a,b} -> {a,b,a,b,a,b}`. This can be shortened to `1ø1ø1ø1ø` or `$2ø\$2ø\`

```
1[$2ø\$2ø\/*-0=][1+]#
```

For some reason, they are using `a-b==0` rather than just `a==b`...

```
1[$2ø\$2ø\/*=][1+]#
```

And then I messed around some more to save 1 character:

```
1[$$3ø\/*2ø=][1+]#
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 25 bytes

```julia
f(n,x=2)=n%x>0?x:f(n,x+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/TSNPp8LWSNM2T7XCzsC@wgosoG2o@b@0ODMvXcEpsThVLyS1uITLoQRIFqeWKCiBGArJQIliJYWk1PTMPIicQpqGoaatrRGcBzTV1hjBMwFyTRFKjYxNTM3MUTQYGhmZGhmZGAAFDS0RGo2NzC2NTM1AwkbGXKl5Kf8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 16 bytes

```
L,RqVAFB]qG$_bUm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJ6gwzNHNKbbQXSU@KTT3////RiYA)

### How it works

```
L,		; Create a lambda function
		; Example argument: [24]
	R	; Range;            [[1 2 3 4 ... 22 23 24]]
	q	; Set;              [{1 2 3 4 ... 22 23 24}]
	V	; Save and pop;     []
	AFB]q	; Push the factors; [{1 2 3 4 6 8 12 24}]
	G	; Retrieve;         [{1 2 3 4 6 8 12 24} {1 2 3 ... 22 23 24}]
	$_h	; Set difference;   [{5 7 9 ... 22 23 24}]
	bUm	; Minimum;          5
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
R‘ḟÆDḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//UuKAmOG4n8OGROG4ov8sw4ck4oKsR///MTAw)

**Explanation:**

```
R‘ḟÆDḢ Example input: 5
R      Range 1 to implicit input. [1,2,3,4,5]
 ‘     Increment. [2,3,4,5,6]
  ḟ    Filter out...
   ÆD  The divisors. [2,3,4,6]
     Ḣ Get the first one. 2
       Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 57 bytes

```
F	F =F + 1
	GT(REMDR(N,F))	:S(RETURN)F(F)
	DEFINE('F(N)')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcy9DgIhEATgGp6C7najhSw/Fy@xgzUWokHuBayNV/j@QUrX8pvMzOe9PbeX72qBhJ0VmxObnbFanRvUfE0Vyp4R1fIYbGstyMCok0qZLyXDxFBwwq5ua7uvbczBov4RCTkhLxSEonyRVUvOhzj/ZRSI/EHuHM1HCnGkuaT@BQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 28 bytes

```
n=>fori=1i<n i++ifn%i breaki
```

Obvious solution, but also short enough for me.

Might be the first time I've used break instead of return competitively.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7P8/WLi2/KNPWMNMmTyFTWzszLU81U6EotaS0KC/zf0FRZl6JRpqGkYmm5n8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
Đ⁺ř|¬ĐŁř*ž↓
```

Explanation:

```
                       Implicitly takes input
Đ                      Duplicates input
 ⁺                     Increments by 1
  ř                    Push [1,2,...,input+1]
   |¬                  Does each of [1,2,...,input+1] not divide the input
     Đ                 Duplicate the array
      Ł                Get the length
       ř               Push [1,2,...,length]
        *              Multiply the top two array elementwise
         ž             Remove all zeroes
          ↓            Get the minimum
                       Implicit print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9weXT//8SQ4oG6xZl8wqzEkMWBxZkqxb7ihpP//zIw)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 48 Bytes

```
function f($n){do{$y++;$d=$n%$y}while($d-eq0)$y}
```

Edited to be a function. I'm not really sure how I would golf the "function" bit, but I'm sure there's a way.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a good first answer, but I think you are assuming that the input is in a variable called `n`. That is not allowed, because [we have some standard Input / Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). I think you could modify your code (currently a snippet) to make it either a function, or a full program accepting input from STDIN / Command Line Arguments. I might be wrong, since I don't know Powershell :)

Answer (score 0):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w) `h` `d`, <del>7</del> 5 bytes

W is doing pretty great, given its lack of a break-out-of-loop instruction!

```
▲²!░╠
```

### Explanation

````
% Since W doesn't support breaking out
% of loops based on a condition, (design
% preference: I don't like while loops):
% We need some reasoning. We know that 
% n and n+1 are always coprime with
% each other, so why not generate a
% range from 1 to n+1?
1+       % Add the inplicit input by 1
     W   % Generate range from 1 to input + 1
         % Keep everything that
         % fullfills the following condition
  bam    % b%a is not falsy (sorry, implicit input
         % isn't working properly)
         % Here, b is the input and a is the current item.

Flag:h % Output the first item of the output
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 58 bytes

```
[S S S T    N
_Push_1][S N
S _Dupe_1][S N
S _Dupe_1][T    N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
T   _Swap][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S T S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_input][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_n][T  S T T   _Modulo][N
T   S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][T N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZNLgUsBiDi5OEFAgYsTzAVJcCqAKLASTgifE0SAVHD@/29kbGRuaWRqZgAA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer input = STDIN as integer
Integer n = 1
Start LOOP:
  n = n + 1
  If(input modulo n == 0):
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
  Print n as integer to STDOUT
  (Implicitly terminate the program with an error because no exit is defined)
```

**Example program flow ([input `24`](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZNLgUsBiDi5OEFAgYsTzAVJcCqAKLASTgifE0SAVHD@/29kAgA)):**

```
Command  Explanation                   Stack        Heap      STDIN  STDOUT  STDERR

SSSN     Push 1                        [1]
SNS      Duplicate 1                   [1,1]
SNS      Duplicate 1                   [1,1,1]
TNTT     Read STDIN as integer         [1,1]        [{1:24}]  24
TTT      Retrieve from heap #1         [1,24]       [{1:24}]
SNT      Swap top two                  [24,1]       [{1:24}]
NSSN     Create Label LOOP             [24,1]       [{1:24}]
SSSTN     Push 1                       [24,1,1]     [{1:24}]
TSSS      Add top two (1+1)            [24,2]       [{1:24}]
STSSTN    Copy (0-based) 1st from top  [24,2,24]    [{1:24}]
STSSTN    Copy (0-based) 1st from top  [24,2,24,2]  [{1:24}]
TSTT      Modulo (24%2)                [24,2,0]     [{1:24}]
NTSN      If 0: Jump to Label LOOP     [24,2]       [{1:24}]

SSSTN     Push 1                       [24,2,1]     [{1:24}]
TSSS      Add top two (2+1)            [24,3]       [{1:24}]
STSSTN    Copy (0-based) 1st from top  [24,3,24]    [{1:24}]
STSSTN    Copy (0-based) 1st from top  [24,3,24,3]  [{1:24}]
TSTT      Modulo (24%3)                [24,3,0]     [{1:24}]
NTSN      If 0: Jump to Label LOOP     [24,3]       [{1:24}]

SSSTN     Push 1                       [24,3,1]     [{1:24}]
TSSS      Add top two (3+1)            [24,4]       [{1:24}]
STSSTN    Copy (0-based) 1st from top  [24,4,24]    [{1:24}]
STSSTN    Copy (0-based) 1st from top  [24,4,24,4]  [{1:24}]
TSTT      Modulo (24%4)                [24,4,0]     [{1:24}]
NTSN      If 0: Jump to Label LOOP     [24,4]       [{1:24}]

SSSTN     Push 1                       [24,4,1]     [{1:24}]
TSSS      Add top two (4+1)            [24,5]       [{1:24}]
STSSTN    Copy (0-based) 1st from top  [24,5,24]    [{1:24}]
STSSTN    Copy (0-based) 1st from top  [24,5,24,5]  [{1:24}]
TSTT      Modulo (24%5)                [24,5,4]     [{1:24}]
NTSN      If 0: Jump to Label LOOP     [24,5]       [{1:24}]

TNST      Print as integer             [24]         [{1:24}]         5
                                                                             error
```

Comment: @Grimmy Thanks and nice fix. I knew I could fix it by adding a `+2`, but then it would have the same 6 bytes as the other 05AB1E answer, which is why I deleted it. But using an infinite list is a smart alternative to fix, at the cost of no additional bytes. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 15 bytes

```perl
1until$_%++$\}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@wNK8kM0clXlVbWyWmtvr/fyOTf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) v2, 5 bytes

```
f≡ⁿℕ₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pvaGDwaP6yR02NOoZGxiamZuZA2sjUyMjEQMfI2Mjc0sjUzOBR2waggodbJ/xPe9S58FHj/kctU4EC////jwIA)

```
   ℕ₁    The output is a positive integer
 ≡ⁿ      which is not an element of
f        the input's factors.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 34 bytes

Note that this does not work for \$n>10000\$ because of Desmos' maximum list length of 10000.

```
r=[2...n+1]
f(n)=r[\mod(n,r)>0][1]
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lgsuijnjxj?nographpaper)

Comment: The code given for the ticker doesn't actually work; If you try pasting in `i->i+\{\mod(n,i)=0\}` verbatim into the ticker you will find that it doesn't paste anything at all. Usually adding a leading newline to the piecewise expression would fix the issue, but due to some weird quirks regarding pasting expressions into tickers, this won't fix the issue either (it might be because the ticker is inherently a "single-line" expression so the "multi-line" expression copy/paste doesn't take effect).

Comment: The only way I can think of to fix this is to separate out the piecewise expression like `a=\{\mod(n,i)=0\}` so that you can use the multi-line copy/paste, then have `i->i+a` in the ticker.

Comment: @Aiden Chow oh, i just directly set \$a\$ to the entire action instead

Comment: You would need a leading newline in your "expression list" unless you swap the two lines.

Comment: Hmmm, I can still paste it without the newline

Comment: Oh yep my bad, I pasted the wrong thing.

Comment: I also just wanted to mention that taking in input in hardcoded variables is [heavily discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2423#2423) if not outright banned by the community, which is what you are doing here with `n`.

Comment: I have a solution with list manipulations, but is longer and doesn't work for \$n>10000\$ because of the list length limit. Should i post that instead?

Comment: It is fine if your program cannot handle all test cases due to an inherent language restriction as long as it theoretically would work for every single case without those restrictions (I don't have a meta post on hand about this but I remember this being true), so the solution you are thinking of (probably the same solution that I'm thinking of) is completely fine.

Comment: As for creating programs with actions, it used to be that you can use `\ans` to get input as that is an [acceptable form of input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/8580#8580), but recently Desmos has taken that functionality out of the main graphing calculator so that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: As for right now, there doesn't seem to be a "meta-compliant" way to get input for actions as far as I can tell. Maybe I'll ask in TNB if hardcoding is okay for now as a special case.

Comment: would (byte count aside) [having a function initialize the variables](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q3kbynzu55), and then starting the ticker, work?

Comment: Hmmm I don't see anything immediately wrong with it, though I'll have to ask to make sure because it does seem like a weird I/O method.